# When a link doesn't exist, how to tell Wordpress what to do? (404 Error Page)

Tags: templates, 404-error, template-hierarchy

If you click any link that doesn't exist in [my main site](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/) site, for example [this link](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/ffffffff/), i expect the WordPress to use the default `index.php` file that has this loop inside it:

```
<div class="main col <?php post_class(); ?>">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content',get_post_format()); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="main col">
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
    <div class="main col">
        <?php get_template_part('content', 'none'); ?>
    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

So i expect WordPress to load the `content-none.php` file, but it doesn't.

> What does this mean? Am I missing any logic that is required to do something that when no real link/page exist do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional you use to output `get_template_part('content', 'none');` is only triggered if there is no post in the main loop, for example, when a category has no posts in it:

```
if (have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        // If the category has a post and we are on a category page, then show the posts
        get_template_part('content', 'archive');
    }
} else {
    //If the category has no posts, display a message that no post exists
    get_template_part('content', 'none');
}
```

But this only happens when you visit `www.example.com/category/some-cat/`, and the `/some-cat/` is actually an existing category slug. If you try to access a page that doesn't exist, the `404.php` template will be used instead.

Comment: ahhhh That means I am missing to create a 404 error page? Right? May be like this → https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Comment: @TheWPNovice Yes, exactly. I added more details to the answer.

Comment: Got it sir. I will create one. I have to wait fro another 7 minutes to accept the answer. I am trying to accept system says wait for another 7 minutes.

Comment: @TheWPNovice That's alright. You should always try the answer and accept it ONLY if it solves your problem, whether directly or indirectly. By the way you can see the page title is `Page Not Found` which indicates you re on a 404 page, but there is no template to display.

Comment: one more thing what is the template hierarchy for 404 page? the primary template is  404.php or something else.

Comment: @TheWPNovice It's a file named `404.php`, located in the templates root folder. I suggest you visit and bookmark [this](https://wphierarchy.com/) website, this will greatly help to understand how templates work.

Comment: Done that is a nice site just like [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/)